# How to mark an order as complete?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-status

I have noticed the default behavior of Magento is to mark the order as complete once the invoice is generated & shipment is made. In my case, I don't want the order to be marked as complete, I want the order to be marked as "Shipping Processing"  I was able to do it by creating a new status ( Processing shipping ) & assigning it to "Complete" order state. Now when an order is invoiced & shipped it assigns the new status as desired ie "Processing shipping", but now I am NOT able to mark the order as complete, I need to at the end move the order to complete.

*My guess, I have assigned my custom order status to the wrong state, ie ( Processing shipping to complete ) hence the system is treating the order as "Complete".* 
                 This is how we fulfill orders:

1. Pending ( New Orders )
2. Processing ( Generate Invoice & Send
   out shipping )
3. Processing Shipping ( Track the shipping )
4. Complete ( Mark the order as complete )

We are stuck between 3 & 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, adding the custom status to "complete" was the right thing to do, you should not try to change the internal meaning of the *states*.

Changing the *status* within the current state is easy. You can select it on the order page, in the "Comment" form. You can leave the "comment" field empty and just change the status:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! Issue Resolved ! This is exactly what i was looking for. Now I am able to move the orders from "Processing Shipping " to "Complete"

Comment: @Saqks if it helped you, please mark the answer as "accepted" with the checkmark on the left side.